# How to communicate between main view model and user control view model

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I have a main view model and it loads some user controls (Stability,Tank) according to some cases. Those user controls have view models like StabilityVM, TankVM. My question is that how to send data from main view model to user control view model or vice versa. My main.xaml and its view model are shown below

**Main window xaml part**

```
<ContentControl  Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding 
ActiveUserControl,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <ContentControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:TankVM}">
                <uc:Tank></uc:Tank>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:StabilityVM}">
                <uc:Stability></uc:Stability>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ContentControl.Resources>

    </ContentControl>
```

**Main View Model Part**

```
public class MainVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    Stability stability;
    Tank tank;
    WeightItem weightItem;
  
    public List<Grid> myControls = new List<Grid>();
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }


    private UserControl activeUserControl;

    public UserControl ActiveUserControl
    {
        get { return activeUserControl; }
        set { activeUserControl = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ActiveUserControl));
        }
    }

    public MainVM()
    {
        //First user control class
        stability = new Stability();
        stability.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        //Second user control class
        tank = new Tank();
        tank.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        ActiveUserControl = stability;
        ActiveUserControl.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        
    }
}
```

Comment: There shouldn't be any UI elements in a view model. If there is e.g. a Tank element in a DataTemplate with `DataType="{x:Type vm:TankVM}"`, you would assign a TankVM object to e.g. the Content property of a ContentControl, and the DataTemplate would automatically be applied. The TankVM object would be automatically assigned to the DataContext of the Tank element. This would only work when you had not explictitly assigned the DataContext of the Tank.

Comment: Besides that, setting `Mode=TwoWay` and `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the Content Binding is pointless. Neither of both has any effect.

Answer (score 0):

To communicate between view models you can use the [mediator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern). Many WPF application frameworks like [Caliburn.Micro](https://caliburnmicro.com/) or [Prism](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/) offer a concrete implementation of this pattern, so you do not have to implement it yourself. Both of them offer a so-called *event aggregator* for communicating via loosely-coupled events.

As an example, in Prism you would define an event type with or without event arguments.

```
// Events derive from PubSubEvent or PubSubEvent<T> if you use event aruments
public class TankChangedEvent : PubSubEvent<TankChangedEventArgs>
{
}

// Event arguments for the above event, uses a property to capture the changed tank
public class TankChangedEventArgs
{
    public Tank Tank { get; }

    TankChangedEventArgs(Tank tank)
    {
        Tank = tank;
    }
}
```

Then in the sender view model you use the event aggregator to publish the event. Note, that you need to create or inject an instance `eventAggregator` of the event aggregator.

```
var args = new TankChangedEventArgs(changedTank);
eventAggregator.GetEvent<PartsDeletedEvent>().Publish(args);
```

In the receiving view model you need to subscribe to the event e.g. in the constructor.

```
eventAggregator.GetEvent<LogicalDirectoriesChangedEvent>().Subscribe(OnTankChanged);
```

Create a method `OnTankChanged` to handle the event when it is received.

```
private void OnLogicalDirectoriesChanged(TankChangedEventArgs args)
{
    // Do something with the event arguments
}
```

You can read about it in detail [here](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/event-aggregator.html). For an example in Caliburn Micro refer to [this site](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/event-aggregator). Although these mechanisms are built into the corresponding frameworks, you can also use them isolated in your project without migrating the whole application. However, there are also other implementations out there, but these frameworks are a good starting point, as they have a comprehensive documentation on that topic.

Comment: But between ViewModel and UserControl it should be different. If I simply change an input box in UserControl do I want to propagate an event for each character? Best would be to reference the UserControlViewModel from MainViewModel and have it always updated.